# Jquery Mobile Dynamic Component Creation

Tags: android, jquery, performance, jquery-mobile

I would like to a create JQM widget/component on the fly. So that i create a custom function to create that.
Please check the below code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>JQM 1.4.2</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css" />

    </head>
    <body>

    <div data-role="page" id="one">
        <div data-role="content">
            <div id="checkboxComponent"></div>               
            <div id="radioComponent"></div>
        </div>
    </div>  

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>  
    <script>        
        var checkBoxArray = ["Car","Bike","Land"];
        var radioBtnArray = ["Car","Bike","Land","House","Farm"];       

        function createComponent(type, element, data) {
            $("#"+element).html('<div data-role="controlgroup" class="controlGruopDiv"></div>');
            for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
                $(".controlGruopDiv").append('<input type="' + type + '" name="' + type + '" id="' + type + i + '"><label for="' + type + i + '">' + data[i] + '</label>');
            };
            $("#"+element).trigger('create');           
        };

        $(document).on("pagecreate", "#one", function(){              
           createComponent("radio", "radioComponent", radioBtnArray);
           createComponent("checkbox", "checkboxComponent", checkBoxArray);
        });
    </script>   
    </body>
</html>
```

The component is render as expected. But the problem is, some duplicate components also be created. If i create anyone component either checkbox or radio, 
(comment this line createComponent("checkbox", "checkboxComponent", checkBoxArray); or createComponent("radio", "radioComponent", radioBtnArray); and check) it is correctly rendered.

I don't what's wrong in the code.

Can anyone suggests the correct way of creating JQM widgets/components on the fly and also advice me which option gives quick and good response in android mobile whether create components dynamically or use static components...Check the below link  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23341638/jquery-mobile-dynamic-components-vs-static-components

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are inserting objects into a controlgroup by class. So the second call finds 2 controlgroups with that class and creates the duplicates you are seeing. Try this instead:

```
function createComponent(type, element, data) {
    var $cgdiv = $('<div data-role="controlgroup" class="controlGruopDiv"></div>');
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        $cgdiv.append('<input type="' + type + '" name="' + type + '" id="' + type + i + '"><label for="' + type + i + '">' + data[i] + '</label>');
    };    

    $("#" + element).empty().append($cgdiv).enhanceWithin();
};
```

This code creates the controlgroup div in memory, appends the inputs, then adds it to the DOM and enhances it.

> Here is a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/6fxz5/)**

Comment: Thank you ezanker...! It's working fine...check the below link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23341638/jquery-mobile-dynamic-components-vs-static-components...which gives us the fast and good performance in android mobiles...

Comment: You are welcome. For the performance difference you will need to test on your supported devices. I don't know the answer...

Comment: Ok... Thank you once again for your valuable answer...!